# Adding a manual legend without extending the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have been trying to add a manual legend to my graph using the following code. However when I add this code it extends the x-axis and I don't understand why.

```
df %>%
  group_by(Site) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Site, y = Phosphate, fill = cut(Phosphate, breaks = c(0, 0.069, 0.173, 1.003, 12)))) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = 0.069, xmin = 0, xmax = 11, fill = '0-0.069'), alpha=.1) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0.069, ymax = 0.173, xmin = 0, xmax = 11, fill = '0.069-0.173'), alpha=.1) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0.173, ymax = 1.003, xmin = 0, xmax = 11, fill = '0.173-1.003'), alpha=.1) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 1.003, ymax = 12, xmin = 0, xmax = 11, fill = '1.003-12'), alpha=.1) +
  geom_boxplot(fill="darkolivegreen3") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 12)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("cell_1_t", "cell_1_b", "cell_2_t",
                              "cell_2_b", "cell_3_t", "cell_3_b",
                              "river_mun_us ", "river_mun_ds"),
                   labels = c("Cell 1 Top", "Cell 1 Bottom", "Cell 2 Top",
                              "Cell 2 Bottom", "Cell 3 Top", "Cell 3 Bottom",
                              "River Upstream", "River Downstream"),
                   expand = c(0, 0)) + # Adjusting the expand argument)+
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 1:6, y = 1, fontface = "bold", label = "(15)") +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 7, y = 3, fontface = "bold", label = "(15)") +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 8, y = 5, fontface = "bold", label = "(15)") +
  ggtitle("River Mun ICW") +
  ylab(expression("Phosphate (mg P L"^-1*")")) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = 'Water Quality',
                    breaks = c('0-0.069', '0.069-0.173', '0.173-1.003', '1.003-12'),
                    labels = c('Good', 'Moderate', 'Poor', 'Bad'),
                    values = c('bisque4', 'bisque3', 'bisque2', 'bisque')) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 1, vjust = -10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 1, hjust = 1, size = 12))+
  theme(legend.position = c(.9, .75),
      legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))
```

[image]

[image]

I have tried the code above, adding a legend using scale_fill_manual. However this has extended the x-axis, but I can't understand why

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: All your `geom_rect`s have an xmax of 11. With a discrete axis, each discrete x axis value is actually put at an integer value. This means that your rectangles make the x axis go from 1 to 11, but your manual x axis only has eight labels, which will be placed at the numbers 1 to 8. You will therefore have too much room on the right. Change your xmax values to 8. Even better, change them to Inf if you want them to go off the page but be ignored by the x axis scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a discrete scale in ggplot, it is actually a continuous scale "under the hood", with the factor levels placed at the integer values. In your example, you have 8 boxes plotted along the x axis, so these will be placed at the integer positions 1 through 8.

The problem is that you are including `geom_rect` layers with an `xmax` value of 11. That means that the x axis will be drawn large enough to included the value 11. There will therefore be 3 units' worth of blank space to the right of your discrete axis labels.

You have not included any data that would allow us to run your code, so let's make a simple reproducible example that is similar to yours. First let us draw the boxplot without the extra `geom_rect` layers:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(x = rep(LETTERS[1:8], each = 20), 
                 y = rnorm(160, 
                           rep(seq(8, 2, len = 8), each = 20), 
                           rep(seq(2, 1, len = 8), each = 20)))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = "#a2cd5a") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = LETTERS[1:8], labels = 1:8) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('bisque3', 'bisque4')) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#ffe8c8", color = 'black'))

p
```

[image]

But look what happens when we add the rectangles:

```r
p +   
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = 0.1, xmin = 0, xmax = 11, fill = 'Good'), 
                alpha = 0.5, data = df[1,]) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = 1, xmin = 0, xmax = 11, fill = 'Bad'), 
            alpha = 0.5, data = df[1,])
```

[image]

If we want the rectangles without them affecting the x axis scale, we can set their minimum value to `-Inf` and maximum value to `Inf`

```r
p +   
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = 0.1, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, fill = 'Good'), 
                alpha = 0.5, data = df[1,]) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = 1, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, fill = 'Bad'), 
            alpha = 0.5, data = df[1,])
```

[image]

Now our x axis scale is unaffected by the `geom_rect` layers and simply fits the box plots.